# Flutter - Como faço para mudar a cor somente da Expanded clicada. Obrigado?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
                  Row(
                      children: lists
                          .map((element) => Expanded(
                              child: new GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    print("Container clicked");
                                    setState(() {
                                      _doop = element;
                                      _isFavorited = true;
                                    });

                                    print(element);
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                      decoration:
                                          myBoxDecoration(), //       <--- BoxDecoration here
                                      child: Text(
                                        element,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            color: (_isFavorited ? Colors.black87 : Colors.yellowAccent),
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                      )))))
                          .toList())
```

Comment: Você poderia reduzir o seu problema a um mínimo de código executável possível, para que as pessoas que fossem te ajudar apenas copiassem, executassem, corrigissem e explicassem a correção/ateração. Quando você disponibiliza apenas metade do código só poderá acontecer duas coisas, a primeira é a pessoa executar o código mentalmente tentando analisar e propor uma mudança que 'pode ser que funcione'. A segunda é ter que perder um tempo a mais apenas para tentar gerar um código executável baseado no seu trecho de código, caçando o nome de variáveis e objetos para poder recriá-lo, fica difícil.

Answer (score -1):

Na hora do click, vc irá da um setState em um atributo de cor para atualizar a cor do Container.  Você pode até utilizar um animated container pra fazer a animação entre cores.

Comment: entao isso faz todas mudarem de cor

Comment: Entendi, falha minha, você precisa dar track no widget atual. Você pode utilizar uma globalKey para cada container. Cada container (caso vc gere eles automaticamente de acordo com seus dados) você pode usar a key como um ID do objeto que você carregou.

Ai utilizando a key salva, você pode fazer uma List das keys e acessar a lista dos seus containers baseado no indice do array. 

Falando parece complicado, mas é uma das soluções possiveis para isso que eu consigo pensar agora.

Answer (score -1):

Voce pode usar um `ExpansionTile` da mesma forma que esta utilizando o Exapanded, e definir a propriedade `backgroundColor` a cor que preferir, e então quando o expanded abrir, ele mudará de cor apenas do mesmo, deixando o diferente dos outros.
Aqui esta um exemplo de como eu o utilizo.

```
_listOfModules = this
    .items
    .map((data) => ExpansionTile(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey[50],
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: getIcon(data),
          ),
          title: Text(data.item.name.keyvalue),
          children:? <Widget>[Text("Nenhum Item encontrado")]
                  : data.items
                      .map((vprocess) => ListTile(
                            title: Text(
                                "${AppTranslations.of(context).text(vprocess.item.title.keyvalue)}"),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                url = vprocess.item.url;
                                title = vprocess.item.title.keyvalue;
                              });
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => RelatorioCard(
                                        url: url, title: title),
                                  ));
                            },
                          ))
                      .toList(),
          onExpansionChanged: (value) {
            if (value) {
              this.getProcess(data);
            }
          },
        )
```

Você pode alterar o `ListTile` pelo seu `GestureDetector` para continuar seguindo seu código.